# Finding a permutation from one list to another

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I am trying to find a formula that would give me a specific permutation mapping one list onto another.

The problem depends on two parameters, $k$ and $n$, such that

- $k$ gives the sequence of integers from $0$ to $k-1$ that will be repeated in one of the list,
- $k^{n-1}$ gives the number of repetitions of said sequences in this list,

and on the following property of the permutation:

- each element of a list is mapped onto the other in order.

---

As an example, for $k = 2$ and $n = 3$, one of the list would be: $\{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1\}$. (The sequence $0, 1$ is repeated 4 times.) This constructs the first list.

The second list is the sorting of the first list. With the above example values, it would read: $\{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1\}$.

The permutation of interest is:
$$
    list_a: \{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1\} \\
    list_b: \{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1\}
$$

- the first $0$ of $list_a$ is mapped on the first $0$ of $list_b$, the second $0$ on the second $0$, and so on.
- similarly for the value $1$.

So the permutation would be: $(1)(2,3,5)(4,7,6)(8)$.

---

Denoting the first constructed list by $list_b$ and the second by $list_a$, the question is: is there a general formula that would give me the specific permutation, as detailed above, from  $list_a$ to $list_b$, given the parameters $k$ and $n$?

Any help (direction to explore, references to read) would be greatly appreciated.

I was able to find programmatically some patterns in these cycles. For instance, for a given $n$, the length of each cycle is either $n$ or $1$. For $n = 2$, the cycles of length $1$ are given by $p \, k + 1$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$, and two successive cycles of length $2$ can be related to one another by adding or subtracting $1$ or $k$ (depending on the position of the elements considered in the cycle).

I do not actually know if such a formula exists, but in view of the properties of the problem and of the expected result, it feels that it might.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "a cycle from list_a to list_b"? A cyclic permutation?

Comment: @Leppala Yes, a cyclic permutation. For the given example values, the cycles from $list_a$ to $list_b$ would be: $(1)(2,3,5)(4,7,6)(8)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your terminology is confusing. The permutation you give as an example is $not$ a cycle (or "cycles" as you wrote). Are you asking for every possible $permutation$ which maps list_a to list_b? Like for example $ \( 1 \)\( 2 \ 5 \)\( 3 \)\( 4 \ 7 \)\( 6 \)\( 8 \) $ or $ \( 1 \)\( 2 \ 5 \ 4 \ 7 \)\( 3 \)\( 6 \)\( 8 \) $ (the latter $is$ a cycle).

Comment: @Leppala Re: terminology. Sorry for the confusion. Re: permutations. I am looking for a general formula, if it exists, that would give me, given $k$ and $n$, one specific permutation. My post is missing the explanation on which permutation I am specifically interested in... Updating it now.

Comment: If we take the case $k = 2$, then we have $2^n$ elements.

The first half (the $2^{n-1}$ zeros) each map to the odd numbered positions and the second half (the $2^{n-1}$ ones) to the even numbered positions. That is: $a \to 2a-1$ for every $a \in \{ 1, \cdots, 2^{n-1}\}$ and $a \to 2(a-2^{n-1})$ for every $a \in \{ 2^{n-1}+1, \cdots, 2^n\}$. This at least gives you the permutation using two-row notation and easily generalizes to any $k$. But I don't know if this helps you.

Comment: @Leppala Yes, this is useful. Thanks for your help.